# django-storage url missing backslash

Tags: django-cms, django-storage

I have a problem with some image source urls. For example I have

`<img src="https://url_to_my_bucket/adminimg/icon_calendar.gif" alt="Kalender"/>`

This code is generated from the django-cms. Fore some reason, there is a '/' missing between the 'admin' and 'img'.

I set the `AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`. If I don't use my s3 bucket everything works fine.

Any ideas, why this '/' is missing?

Comment: I've seen this issue as well recently & I believe it comes from the javascript but I've not found a solution yet.

Comment: How are you using AWS, do you have storages & boto installed with `STATICFILES_STORAGE` set?